# Formatting output of Write-verbose

Tags: powershell

I have a script which when i output an array of file information like this i get the following output

```
$output
Productversion Fileversion FileName
1.2.3.4         1.2.3.4     test.exe
```

However when i do output it in the following way

```
write-verbose $output
```

I lose the nice output and get everything for each line of $output. Is it possible to format the verbose output to look like standard output? (I need to use write-verbose for a powershell on remote machine TFS task)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$output | Out-String | Write-Verbose
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. Now i feel pretty dumb for not figuring this out myself